# How to stall on agreeing to a job offer?

Tags: job-offer, negotiation

I have a preliminary job offer from a company, they booked a flight for me to go have lunch with the team and potentially sign the contract if both sides see fit. They already drafted a contract and sent me a copy to read. They have asked me to bring some documents when I visit them, so I do believe they will ask me to sign the contract when I am there. I really like this company, but I have a final-round on-site interview somewhere else and I would like to also hear from the other company prior to accepting an offer from the first company. How can I stall on agreeing to the first company's preliminary offer?

Comment: How much are you willing to risk the job you have over a job offer that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: This answer may be specific to the country and industry.

Comment: Did they ask you for the travel dates before booking the flight?

Comment: Did you verbally accept? Usually an contract is only written after all terms are agreed upon.

Answer (score 3):

You quickly talk to the other companies, and let them know you have an offer on the table, and ask if they are able to expedite their process.

When you go to lunch with the job that has the offer, you might try negotiating some aspects in the contract, or ask if you can take a couple more days to decide.  Since you've already seen the contract, you don't have a lot of time.

Then, you have a couple of days to decide.

You can then either turn them down, and hope that one of the other jobs comes through (and if they expedited things, you may have a better idea on whether that is likely to happen).  Or you can sign the contract, and let the other companies know that you are no longer available.

In other words, from the time you see the contract, you have time to negotiate and evaluate, but you don't have a lot of time.  If you can get another job offer in that time, then great.  Otherwise, you have to choose between a solid job offer or a potential job offer, knowing that whatever you choose, the other option goes away.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. OP can *also* say that he is interviewing with another company, and he wants some time to weigh options up. there's nothing wrong with being upfront about multiple offers, in fact, it's always highly advised to do so.

Comment: Not sure about  "you carefully read the contract". The OP already has the contract and I think the employer expects that he/she reads it and sort out any questions before getting on a plane.

Comment: @Hilmar you're right, I read that wrong.  Let me adjust my wording.  That kind of means the OP has less time to stall.

Answer (score -1):

I'd be careful here. It feels like Employer A expects you do sign the contract if you board the plane. You have all information (including the contract itself) and you can sort out any questions around that before you incur a non-trivial expense. There is always something that may turn up during the actual visit, but that's supposed to be more of an exception and less of "I'm still thinking about it".

Dragging your feet may not leave a good first impression.

So unless Employee B has a good likelihood of a) happening and b) resulting in a significantly better job, I'd give full priority to A. In this case it's easy: you approach B with full transparency: *"I have a good offer on the table and need to decide by xxx. I'd love to explore this further with you, but it has to happen inside this time frame."*

It's not an unusual or unreasonable request. Recruiter and/or hiring manager may not be super happy about it, but they are used it and they'd appreciate the openness now they know the constraints wo work with. They may chose not do accommodate you, but then you still have Employee A and it's also a sign that Employee B wasn't super exited about you either